# Instance on Points with different parameters for each instance

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances

I'm fairly new to Geometry Nodes.
I'm trying to create a certain amount of $90°$ arcs using Geometry Nodes, where each arc has a different radius but a common center point, such that the distance between each arc is constant.

[image]

I also want the arcs to only start after a certain threshold value (`t` in this example)

My current setup is as follows:

[image]

That yields the following result:

[image]

Currently the center of each arc moves along the initially generated line. Instead of that, I want to keep the center the same but change the radius instead. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Since an arc by default is drawn with the compass needle in the origin, once it becomes an instance, scaling the instance will look like simply modifying the radius - without displacing the arc. So if you create an arc with $r=1$, the (uniform) scale of the instance will equal its radius:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this task as follows:

[image]

Here, I first convert the arc into an instance, so that I can easily scale it to a specific value at the end.

I achieve the duplication not by instantiating on a *Mesh Line* but directly with the node `Duplicate Elements`.

With the index of the duplicate I can then on the one hand remove the instances at the beginning, and on the other hand do the scaling.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.6+)*</sub>